# How do I get my List Box to display the actual names of my properties in my entity framework data base

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, listbox, bindinglist

My list box is showing the data but not the actual names of it here is some code I used to display it but its not showing the names.

```
     public void WireUpList()
    {
        FoodListBox.DataSource = GetFood();
        
    }

     
    private BindingList<Food> GetFood()
   {

        var foodList = nRIDataContext.FoodModels.ToList();
        
        var listBinding = new BindingList<Food>(foodList);

        return listBinding;


    }
```

At first I had my method as a List not a binding list and I thought that was the solution but I'm still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Specify the Property to use as the `DisplayMember` (the text presented in the Control). E.g., `FoodListBox.DisplayMember = "Name"; FoodListBox.DataSource = GetFood();`. Or override `ToString()` in the `Food` class.

Comment: If you need to show the values of multiple Properties, use a DataGridView instead.